# How can I know exactly what files are put in the computer from a software installation?

Tags: windows-7, installation, uninstall

If I want to uninstall a program manually by deleting all the files that were installed, how can I know what the files installed are either during the installation or after?

Do software installations make changes to the registry?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that ( deleting all the files).  Some may be existing files that were replaced.  The original was probably saved somewhere, the uninstall - if any good - will restore the original version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most software installations make changes to the Registry.

You would somehow have to record all the changes made during the installation. One way to do this is to run [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) during the installation.
You can find an example of how this is done [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/aaron_margosis/the-case-of-the-app-install-recorder) .

You may find that the latest version of Process Monitor does not run on Windows 7.

Comment: ProcessMonitor 3.60 runs fine on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Or use this tool 'whatchanged'.
https://www.google.com/search?q=whatchanged&oq=whatchanged&aqs=chrome..69i57.3840j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
it compares a before and after snapshot.
Slow but handy.